# Use reference to dynamically created control in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a form in Word 2003 to collect multiple responses to a single question. I have a macro on a button press which duplicates the various input fields (drop-down boxes, radio buttons etc.) ready for a new response.

However, I need to change the text of the radio buttons, and set the `OnChange` event on a combobox, and I can't find the correct syntax to do so. Both the controls are from the 'Control Toolbox' toolbar.

The macro code I have to duplicate the controls is below.

```
Private Sub CommandButton11_Click() 
Set Doc = ActiveDocument
Response = MsgBox("Add another response?", vbYesNo, "Confirm action")
    If Response = vbYes Then
        If Doc.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
          Doc.Unprotect
        End If

        Selection.MoveRight
        Selection.MoveDown
        Selection.TypeParagraph
        ''# keep the reference to this control and set the OnChange event handler
        Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1"
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
        Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
        Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
        ''# keep the reference to this control and set text
        Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl ClassType:="Forms.OptionButton.1"
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

        Doc.Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

adding the event handlers dynamically is a bit tricky.

You could add the code dynamically to ThisDocument. This is the way described by Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B246299&x=14&y=10. However, when I tried this Word 2007 crashed.

Another way is to add a class for event handling and create an instance of this class for each control. Place the following code into a module:

```
Option Explicit

Public objControls() As clsComboBox

Private Sub CommandButton11_Click()
    Dim objShape As InlineShape

    If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
        ActiveDocument.Unprotect
    End If

    Selection.MoveRight
    Selection.MoveDown
    Selection.TypeParagraph
    ' keep the reference to this control and set the OnChange event handler
    Set objShape = Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1")
    With objShape.OLEFormat.Object
        .AddItem "Item 1"
        .AddItem "Item 2"
    End With

    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
    Selection.TypeText Text:=vbTab
    ' keep the reference to this control and set text
    Set objShape = Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEControl(ClassType:="Forms.OptionButton.1")
    With objShape.OLEFormat.Object
        .Caption = "My great option"
    End With
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

    ActiveDocument.Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, NoReset:=True

    ' we have to execute the creation of the event handlers with a delay
    ' to make it work (seems Word needs some time for object creation)
    Application.OnTime When:=Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), Name:="prcCreateReference"

End Sub

Public Sub prcCreateReference()
    Dim objShape As InlineShape
    Dim intCount As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each objShape In ThisDocument.InlineShapes
        intCount = intCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve objControls(1 To intCount)
        If TypeOf objShape.OLEFormat.Object Is ComboBox Then
            Set objControls(intCount) = New clsComboBox
            Set objControls(intCount).ComboBox = objShape.OLEFormat.Object
        ElseIf TypeOf objShape.OLEFormat.Object Is OptionButton Then
            ' add event handlers for option buttons
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This code should go into a class module named clsComboBox:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents mobjComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox

Friend Property Set ComboBox(objComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox)
    Set mobjComboBox = objComboBox
End Property

Private Sub mobjComboBox_Change()
    MsgBox "Selection changed."
End Sub

Private Sub mobjComboBox_Click()
    MsgBox "Clicked."
End Sub
```

Note that the variable objControls must be of type clsComboBox. Declaring this variable as Object or Variant didn't work for me (could anyone explain why???).

Comment: Nice work.  I found I could get away with a much smaller delay for the `Application.OnTime` call.  I used:  `Application.OnTime VBA.Now + 0.000001, "prcCreateReference"` which is slightly less than 1/10th of a second.   Oh, and I'm using Word 2007.